# Calculate simple trajectory

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working with OpenGL developing a simple (very simple) game. I came across a problem with calculating a missile trajectory (unfortunately don't have many math skills).

I'm working with $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates. My target is set at coordinates $(40,40,0)$ and my missile launcher is at $(40,0,50)$ with a zero angle.

I'm discarding gravitational forces and other forces.

If my missile position was perpendicular to my target and with a zero angle, and an constant velocity, if I fire the missile, it would go at a given rate, decreasing is $z$ coordinate and stop at $z=0$.

My problem is if the missile is not perpendicular to the target and if it as an angle.

So my simple question is how can I calculate the trajectory, my target is set at some coordinates and my missile launcher at another coordinates and with some angle?

Comment: To calculate the trajectory, we need to know the direction of firing. This will be a 3D vector, $(x,y,z)$. You say the launcher has "zero angle". Does that mean you're firing horizontally? If so, we know that $z=0$. We need $x$ and $y$, too.

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed that we are supposed to ignore gravity. So I suppose the direction of firing is directly towards the target.

Comment: @bubba Thanks. Yes. To make it more simple lets ignore  gravity. Imagine the missile launcher is at an 25 degree angle ($y$ coordinate) at the position ($40,0,50$) with a 15 degree angle at the $z$ coordinate (it's not facing front to the "wall"). The direction of firing is where the "wall" is, at $z=0$. I need to know with that position of the missile where is he going to hit the wall. Since i'm ignoring gravity, it will be a straight line.

Comment: This seems like a completely different question. What's this "wall" thing? How (from where) are the angles measured? If the angles specify the direction of firing, then what's the relevance of the target? A picture would probably help.

Comment: Sorry. Missed this comment. The "wall" thing is the plane were the target is placed. The angles are measured from the position of the missile. If the missile is at (40,0,50) the angle is measured between $z$ and $y$ for the vertical position and from the $z$ and $x$ for the horizontal position

Answer (score 1):

I assume we fire directly at the target. Suppose the speed of the bullet is $v$. Then, at time $t$, the position of the bullet will be
\begin{align*}
x &= 40     \\
y &= 40vt/d        \\
z &= 50 - 50vt/d
\end{align*}
where $d = \sqrt{4100}$ is the distance between the launch site and the target. You can check that the bullet reaches the target when $t = d/v$.

Comment: Thanks bubba. Where does the value 4100 comes from? And if we do not fire directly at the target?

Comment: I explained the 4100. If you don't fire directly at ther target, you need to specify the direction vector. See comments above.

Comment: Thanks. Lets say the missile is at (40,0,50) ant the direction target is (20,10,0) it would be $x = 20; y= 10vt/d;z = 50-50vt/d$??